# Where is the console output log file in CloudBees?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

According to [Administering Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) I should be able to find it in $JENKINS_HOME but when I even try to

```
ls $JENKINS_HOME
```

I get the error

```
ls: cannot access /home/jclouds/hudson_home/: No such file or directory
```

I've searched all over the filesystem and cannot find the log. It's not even in `/var/log`.

Where is the console output log file in CloudBees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$JENKINS_HOME` is a directory on the Jenkins master computer. Since CloudBees-hosted Jenkins will never run builds on the master, only on slaves, this directory will never be accessible. Indeed for security reasons the master’s filesystem is not made available to users, only to CloudBees support personnel.

If you want to see your Jenkins log file, just go to https://ACCOUNT.ci.cloudbees.com/log/all (*Manage Jenkins » System Log » All Jenkins Logs*).

Comment: To get it from within an execute shell command I've been using `curl -sO $BUILD_URL/consoleText`

Comment: So you are talking about a build log, not the Jenkins console log. Unrelated things.

Comment: I was talking about the console log. Where can I find the build log?